# Why do non-constant static variables need to be initialized outside the class?

Tags: c++, static

I know that non-constant static variables need to be initialized outside the class definition but, is there a reason for this?

```
class A {
    static int x = 0 // compile error;
    static int y;
};

int A::y = 0; // fine
```

Comment: Related: [C++ static member variable and its initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547660/c-static-member-variable-and-its-initialization), [Why does a static data member need to be defined outside of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749071/why-does-a-static-data-member-need-to-be-defined-outside-of-the-class)

Comment: There's great value in duplicate questions: new questions usually get new answers which take into account modern developments in the technology and language.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Essentially it's because `x` exists independently of the number of *instances* of `A` that are created.

So storage for `x` needs to be defined somewhere - you can't rely on an instance of `A` to do that, and that's what

```
A::x = 0;
```

in exactly one translation unit, does.

Comment: Seems logical, but you could use the same reasoning for static member methods, and they can still be defined within the class.  Even taking the address of the static member method across multiple compilation units yields the same address, so the linker somehow manages to 'merge' the multiple definitions of the static member method.  Then why doesn't the linker to this for static data members? (note: this is mainly about the fact that it needs to be defined outside the class, not related to the initialization itself).

Comment: @Patrick This may be one of the reasons why inline variable is introduced.

Comment: @Patrick members defined within a class are implicitly `inline`...  This answer would be improved by mentioning C++17 inline variables.

Comment: For methods there is a strong motivation for allowing definitions in multiple translation units. The compiler needs access to a definition to inline stuff and inlining is important for performance. For variables this is less nessacery.

Comment: @Yakk that's only about methods. To ODR-use a static member variable you must use `inline` keyword or define it outside the class.

Comment: @Ruslan Oops, that "members" was supposed to be "methods".  Darn "m" words.

Comment: upvote @Yakk-AdamNevraumont's last comment otherwise if overlooked his previous comment would be hardly correct

Answer (score 20):

When the `const` qualifier is present, the static variable can be considered as a constant expression. Initializing it in the class definition goes to that effect. It's just some constant value, may not even need any storage.

But in the other case, it's not a constant expression. It definitely needs storage. And as @Bathsheba points out, it needs to be defined in only one translation unit (pre-C++17). Generally speaking, a declaration that contains an initializer is also a definition. So it just can't be initialized when declared.

---

Starting with C++17, that variable can be an inline variable. So the definition can in fact be included with the class declaration

```
class A {
  static inline int x = 0;
};
```

And the compiler will sort out all those declarations to mean the same storage.

Answer (score 3):

after a small research, found this (from [bogotobogo](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/statics.php)) :

> we cannot initialize a static member variable inside the class declaration. ***That's because the declaration is a description of how memory is to be allocated, but it doesn't allocate memory. We allocate and initialize memory by creating an object using that format.***
>
> In the case of a static class member, we initialize the static member independently, with a separate statement outside the class declaration. That's because the static class member is stored separately rather than as part of an object.
>
> The exception to the initialization of a static data member inside the class declaration is if the static data member is a const of integral or enumeration type.

---

---

my take from this is ..

static members exist as members of the class rather than as an instance in each object of the class.

when you initialize the static variable inside the class declaration, *as a concept* it will be re-initialized (not the actual behaviour) on every creation of an object/instance of the class,
[since the class declaration is the blueprint of which every new object of the class is construct].

but we know that this is not supposed to be the behavior of a static member, so the initialization of this member is outside of the class declaration.

I found this explanation a more intuitive one, but still the formal explanation remains the first one.

Answer (score -3):

Apart from what others have said, there is currently no place (pre C++ 11) within a class where you could initialize a static member (because members (both static and non-static can't be initialized where declared). For non-static members, we use either the `constructor` or the `member initializer list` to do the initialization. But this means we have to create an instance of the class.

Since a static member initialization can't depend on an instance being created, it's done outside the class where the member is declared.

Comment: I think most people would read/interpret that sentence differently. I simply meant something like ( struct a { int x=5; }  )

Comment: Well, I do have an old compiler but you could've said that right away, would've saved both of us some time.

Comment: I did try to say as much, but mispoke. I meant to say [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members). So for that I do apologise. Btw, you can check such snippets in online compiler front ends.

Comment: OK, thank you, will look it up. Also, I see that the OP didn't mention which compiler he's using, so I guess my post is not entirely wrong (for pre C++11 compilers, that is)