# Default argument for a class function defined in constructor

Tags: c++, oop, static-variables, static-initialization, default-arguments

Is there a possibility to define a variable that will be used as a default argument in the constructor?

```
#include <iostream>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x) { num = x;}
    void print(int y = num)
    {
        std::cout << y << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static int num;
};
int main()
{
    Foo f(5);
    f.print();
}
```

this compiles but I get linking errors `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static int Foo::num" (?num@Foo@@0HA)`

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749071/why-does-a-static-data-member-need-to-be-defined-outside-of-the-class

Comment: So, if  I understood that  correctly its impossible?

Comment: If num wasn't static, you could do this.

Comment: @IlyaS when num is not static i get `a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, you just have to declare/initialize the static variable outside the class:

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UlYOGKt8V5n77qZu)

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{ 
    //..
};

int Foo::num; //<-- or 'int Foo::num = 0;'

int main()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that is still hard coded, I want num to be user defined

Comment: @SzymonO, you just have to declare/initialize it outside the class, the value doesn't have to be used, then it can be defined by the user, see the demo code.

Comment: Ohhh, ok I get it now. Huge thanks :)